# PHP, AJAX, JSON - exchange of data between two pages

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have two web pages and i'm using javascript (ajax) to call a php page.
I would like to receive the json file from change.php to the script in client.html for printing the result. 
The problem is: I don't know how to send the json file to the script in client.html for printing the result 
Here are the pages:

**client.html**

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="toEncode" name="toEncode"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="changeFunction()"/>
</form>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeFunction(){
    var userName = $('#toEncode').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "change.php",
        data: { "msg": toEncode},
        success: function (response){
            window.alert("Done!");
           //decode json and print the result
        }
    });
}
```

**change.php**

```
<?php
 $temp= $_POST["msg"];
 $temp2= $temp.' ,hi';
 json_encode($temp2);
?>
```

Comment: So, what exactly promblem is ?

Comment: *JS* : `data: userName`. *PHP* : `$_POST["userName"]`

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: Your setting `var userName`, `toEncode` is undefined

Comment: I've to pass the json from change.php to the scirpt and print the result in client.html but i don't know how to send it to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
 <input type="text" id="toEncode" name="toEncode"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="changeFunction()"/>
</form>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeFunction(){
    var userName = $('#toEncode').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "change.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "msg": userName},
        success: function (response){
            window.alert("Done!");
           //decode json and print the result
        }
    });
}
```

**Change.php**

```
<?php
 $temp= $_POST["msg"];
 $temp2= $temp.' ,hi';
 echo  json_encode($temp2);
 die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable name:

var toEncode = $('#toEncode').val();

Answer (score 0):

In your above code, you have set the key `msg` to an `undefined` value of `toEncode`.

You have also retrieved the `userName` value but never used it.

I think you just got confused about what exactly to type.

**Solution**

```
let userName = $('#toEncode').val();

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "change.php",
  data: {
    msg: userName
  },
  success: function(response) {
    window.alert("Done!");
  }
});
```

No modifications needed for `change.php`